# how draw rectangle with four div inside container in html5 with using only css?

Tags: html, css

how use css only for build rectangle from this code below ?

```html
<div id='rectangle'>
    <div class='line'></div>
    <div class='line'></div>
    <div class='line'></div>
    <div class='line'></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but if you just want to draw a rectangle, you can use the CSS `border` property, see https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

Comment: thanks i searched before on google   i found only draw rectangle with different class names but all my lines should have same name like my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rZaeXr

```
.line:first-child {
 width: 100px;
  height: 4px;
  background: red;
}

.line:nth-child(2) {
 width: 100px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.line:nth-child(3) {
 width: 100px;
  height: 4px;
  background: red;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-56px, 50px);
}

.line:nth-child(4) {
 width: 100px;
  height: 4px;
  background: red;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-60px, -50px);
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer this is what i need

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following. I don't recommend using an `id` for styling. If for some reason you want multiple `rectangle` than and `id` is not the way to go. This is because and `id` can be seen as an `identification` for a person. Meaning an `id` should be unique on the page.

```css
.rectangle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  background: red; 
}


.top, .bottom {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.top {
  top: 0;
}

.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
}

.left, .right {
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  top: 0;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle">
  <div class="line top"></div>
  <div class="line right"></div>
  <div class="line bottom"></div>
  <div class="line left"></div>
</div>
```

or:

```css
.rectangle {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for answer but class name should be 'line'

Comment: @test don't expect SO to always provide a copy paste answer. The name of the class doesn't matter